Pandoc, equations and OpenOffice writer
I found an elegant way to convert .tex files to .docx format. The text rendering is really good, but some things are missing:

The equations are not displayed: I think it is a problem with OO Writer, since they are displayed with MS Word;
to try to export the images created synthetically with tikz, I used this filter in python and pandoc --from latex+raw_tex --filter=tikz.py -s test.tex -o test.docx line command, but process stops with the error message ! LaTeX Error: Environment axis undefined.;
I made an attempt with latex2rtf: I installed the app, but by launching the latex2rtf command on the prompt this command is non-existent.

MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{amsmath,tcolorbox,tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis} 
        \addplot [brown,dotted,very thick] {x^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

I use Windows 10 OS. Is there a solution to these problems?

For your second bullet point: you might want to add the pgfplots package to the script

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz isn't already defined on the MWE 2nd line?

The script you linked to uses its own preamble to convert the tikzpictures to images. It does not use your preamble.

Sorry, I'm new to Python. Could you tell me how I can define the use of the package within the script?

Search for \\usepackage{tikz} in the script and start experimenting from there. I'm sure you'll manage to add another package.
